# How to add properties to a metaclass instance?

Tags: python, properties, metaclass

I would like to define metaclass that will enable me to create properties (i.e. setter, getter) in new class on the base of the class's attributes.

For example, I would like to define the class:

```
class Person(metaclass=MetaReadOnly):
    name = "Ketty"
    age = 22

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name: " + str(self.name) + "; age: "
                + str(self.age))
```

But I would like to get something like this:

```
class Person():
    __name = "Ketty"
    __age = 22

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name;
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        raise RuntimeError("Read only")

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self.__age
    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        raise RuntimeError("Read only")

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Name: " + str(self.name) + "; age: "
                + str(self.age))
```

Here is the metaclass I have written:

```
class MetaReadOnly(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):

        result_dct = {}

        for key, value in dct.items():
            if not key.startswith("__"):
                result_dct["__" + key] = value

                fget = lambda self: getattr(self, "__%s" % key)
                fset = lambda self, value: setattr(self, "__"
                                                   + key, value)

                result_dct[key] = property(fget, fset)

            else:
                result_dct[key] = value

        inst = super(MetaReadOnly, cls).__new__(cls, clsname,
                                                bases, result_dct)

        return inst

    def raiseerror(self, attribute):
        raise RuntimeError("%s is read only." % attribute)
```

However it dosen't work properly.

```
client = Person()
print(client)
```

Sometimes I get:

`Name: Ketty; age: Ketty`

sometimes:

`Name: 22; age: 22`

or even an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(client)
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 34, in __str__
    return ("Name: " + str(self.name) + "; age: " + str(self.age))
  File "F:\Projects\TestP\src\main.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    fget = lambda self: getattr(self, "__%s" % key)
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute '____qualname__'
```

I have found example how it can be done other way [Python classes: Dynamic properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503165111/http://znasibov.info/blog/html/2010/03/10/python-classes-dynamic-properties.html), but I would like to do it with metaclass. Do you have any idea how this can be done or is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Bind the *current* value of `key` to the parameter in your `fget` and `fset` definitions:

```
fget = lambda self, k=key: getattr(self, "__%s" % k)
fset = lambda self, value, k=key: setattr(self, "__" + k, value)
```

---

This is a classic Python pitfall. When you define

```
fget = lambda self: getattr(self, "__%s" % key)
```

the value of `key` is determined when `fget` is called, not when `fget` is defined. Since it is a nonlocal variable, its value is found in the enclosing scope of the `__new__` function. By the time `fget` gets called, the `for-loop` has ended, so the *last* value of `key` is the value found. Python3's `dict.item` method returns items in a unpredictable order, so *sometimes* the last key is, say, `__qualname__`, which is why a suprising error is sometimes raised, and sometimes the same wrong value is returned for all attributes with no error.

---

When you define a function with a parameter with a default value, the default value is bound to the parameter at the time the function is defined. 
Thus, the current values of `key` get corrected bound to `fget` and `fset` when you bind default values to `k`.

Unlike before, `k` is now a local variable. The default value is stored in `fget.__defaults__` and `fset.__defaults__`.

---

Another option is to use a [closure](http://effbot.org/zone/closure.htm). You can define this outside of the metaclass:

```
def make_fget(key):
    def fget(self):
        return getattr(self, "__%s" % key)
    return fget
def make_fset(key):
    def fset(self, value):
        setattr(self, "__" + key, value)
    return fset
```

and use it inside the metaclass like this:

```
result_dct[key] = property(make_fget(key), make_fset(key))
```

Now when `fget` or `fset` is called, the proper value of `key` is found in the enclosing scope of `make_fget` or `make_fset`.

Answer (score 0):

@unutbu's answer is perfectly fine and addressed the main caveats very well.

However, there is one more thing to note (I cannot comment yet so here I am posing an entire answer), note that `classproperty`'s and `instanceproperty`'s have different keys.

What you are doing here is entirely based on class properties. If one wishes to make a setter for an "instance" property the key must be `f"_{clsname}__{key}"`. I lack the technical understanding of Python data model to explain why or if what I'm saying is entirely correct or has other caveats. Just posting this here as a side note.

This is especially important if you wish to allow the user to override the methods with custom ones like the example I provide here (I'm not sure even if it has no syntax error but still I post it here):

```py
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, info, **kwargs):
        property_key = "__my_private"  # should have been f"_{clsname}__my_private"
        info[property_key] = "default_value"
        if "my_getter" not in info:
            info["my_getter"] = lambda self, key=property_key: getattr(self, key)
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, info, **kwargs)

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def my_getter(self):
        return f"will fail to get {self.__my_private}"

MyClass().my_getter() # => Raises: AttributeError "_MyClass__my_private" not found.
# This would work so fine if no `self` keyword was being used (treated as classproperty)
```